# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am using srmklive/paypal:~1.0 in my project i am getting this error
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in C:\laragon\www\PaymentMethod\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72

i am trying to pass my data in the controller as such

```
 public function pay()
    {

       $data = [];
       $data['items'] = [
           [
               'name' => 'nikeshoes',
               'price' => 200,
               'desc'  => 'nike shoes',
               'qty' => 1
           ]
       ];

       $data['invoice_id']=16;
       $data['invoice_description'] = "Order #{$data['invoice_id']} Invoice";
       $data['return_url'] = route('paymentapproval');
       $data['cancel_url'] = route('cancel');
       $data['total'] = 200;

       $provider = new ExpressCheckout;

       $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);

       $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);

       return redirect($response['paypal_link']);



    }

    public function cancel()
    {
        dd("something");
    }
    public function paymentapproval(Request $request)
    {
        $provider=new ExpressCheckout;

        $response = $provider->getExpressCheckoutDetails($request->token);
      // $response = $provider->doExpressCheckoutPayment($data, $token, $PayerID);

        if (in_array(strtoupper($response['ACK']), ['SUCCESS', 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING'])) {
            dd('Your payment was successfully. You can create success page here.');
        }

        dd('Something is wrong.');

    }
```

i have also changed my paypal.php file inside the config folder

```
 return [
        'mode' => 'sandbox',        // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.
        'sandbox' => [
            'username' => '',       // Api Username
            'password' => '',       // Api Password
            'secret' => '',         // This refers to api signature
            'certificate' => '',    // Link to paypals cert file, storage_path('cert_key_pem.txt')
        ],
        'live' => [
            'username' => '',       // Api Username
            'password' => '',       // Api Password
            'secret' => '',         // This refers to api signature
            'certificate' => '',    // Link to paypals cert file, storage_path('cert_key_pem.txt')
        ],
        'payment_action' => 'Sale', // Can Only Be 'Sale', 'Authorization', 'Order'
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'notify_url' => 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com',         // Change this accordingly for your application.
    ];
```

inside my env file setting are

```
PAYPAL_MODE=sandbox

#PayPal Setting & API Credentials - sandbox
PAYPAL_SANDNOX_API_USERNAME=sb-crlzo6945665_api1.business.example.com
PAYPAL_SANDNOX_API_PASSWORD=password of the api
PAYPAL_SANDNOX_API_SECRET=api secret 
PAYPAL_CURRENCY=MYR
```

don't know what is causing this error and how to remove it will be thank ful to u

Comment: I was having the same exact error while returning an object like this: `return $myObject`, I had to change into `return ['myKey' => $myObject]`  of course `myObjet` is not an Eloquent model because returning Eloquent model  is automatically serialised. hope this can help

Comment: same boat! did anybody find a solution?

Comment: looks like i used the same tutorial as you, too!